# APC install fails due to Missing Dependency?

Tags: linux, php, centos

I'm trying to run the following on a CentOS Linux 5.5 (w/ PHP 5.2.10):
yum install php-pear php-devel httpd-devel

but it fails with this:

php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)
php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)

Any ideas? I cannot find anything on Google which would point me to the right location.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the version of `php-devel` that matches the version of `php` already installed on the system. Try looking where you originally acquired it from.

Comment: Cheers. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Nope. I have no clue where you got your current `php` package from. Try checking the output of `rpm -qi php` for clues.

Comment: My provider solved it for me. Here's the solution: yum --enablerepo <my-repo> install php-pear httpd-devel php-devel